# How to find expected value and variance of $a^X$, where a is positive.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value

How to find the expected value and variance of $a^X$, where a is positive. $X$ is a Poisson random variable with $\lambda$. This is very interesting, $X$ is at the exponential position. I only know the moment generating function, should we let $Y=a^X$, then write $E[Y]$ as sum of the value of $Y$ times the corresponding probability? But it seems very hard to discuss.

For variance, we can use the formula, but we still need to find $E[a^X]$ first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y=a^X$, so $Y$ takes the value $a^n$ with probability $f_X(n)$ where $f_X(m)$ is the PMF of $X$.

You can use $E[g(X)]=\sum_{x=0}^\infty g(x)f_X(x)$ or if you know the MGF of $X$ i.e $M_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]$, then simply substitute $t=\ln a$ into it which will give you $E[(e^{\ln a})^X]=E[a^X]$.

For the variance, you will additionally need $E[Y^2]=E[(a^2)^X]$. Once again substitute $t=\ln(a^2)=2\ln a$ into the MGF.

Comment: It works! Thanks.